Login callback goes to AWS IP instead of the domain
I have hosted my app to AWS with Cloudfront.
I am using socialite for Social login.
Facebook login works fine, but in Google login, it callback to ec2-x-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast.AmazonAWS... Insted of callback to my URL.
For this I am getting InvalidStateException.
I have tried with stateless but no luck.
    public function redirectGoogleLogin()
    {
      
        return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
    }
    
    public function callbackGoogleLogin()
    {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
    }


Have you tried setting the correct, full URL of the callback (with protocol and domain) in the redirect config value of Socialite? If you only set a relative path there, it may perhaps end up using the wrong domain.
